# Square API to create merchant account?

Tags: flutter, square-connect, square

I am creating an app where sellers can sign up on an app, and sell products (think Etsy). Local users can view and purchase the product from the seller.

What would be the best approach for doing this? I was looking at the Square API. I looked through Square's Merchant API but could not find an endpoint to create a new Merchant account (which I would ideally create for each seller). Another option might be to create one Merchant account (for the app) and a new Location for each seller. Does this seem like a good idea?

Answer (score 0):

At this time the ability to create merchant accounts with Square APIs isn't currently available. We’re constantly working to improve our features based on feedback like this, so I’ll be sure to share your request to the API product team.

It isn't recommended to have all payments run through one Square account cause you'd have to deal with all of the chargeback risk for every payment and all the payouts of funds to the sellers.